# Getting a variable by name using reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I've got a Java class which contains a Color object called fillColor, along with several other colors;

Reflection is probably overkill for this, in fact I may just end up using a map, but either way this is worth asking.

Here's a method of that class which returns a color based on a string.

```
public Color getColor(String name) {
    Field field;
    Color c= new Color();
    try{
        field = getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        System.out.println(field.get(c));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("wtf happened here?");
    }

    return c;
}
```

this throws an exception. It's message reads

```
Can not set com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color field com.whatever.project.Hexagon.fillColor to com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color
```

Obviously I'm confused. Is this message telling me I can't assign a Color field to a Color variable?

**EDIT: stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color field com.whatever.project.Hexagon.fillColor to com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at com.whatever.project.Hexagon.getColor(Hexagon.java:177)
    at com.whatever.project.Animator$1.animate(Animator.java:45)
    at com.whatever.project.Animator.animate(Animator.java:86)
    at com.whatever.project.Project.render(BlackDot.java:40)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

fillColor is declared like this:

```
Color fillColor;
```

Comment: I bet fillColor requires another class named "Color" that is not the same

Comment: You need to call `getClass()` on Color instead of silent `this`, also what is the actual declaration `fillColor`?

Comment: getColor() is inside of the class Hexagon which contains fillColor. I'm calling getClass() on this, which is Hexagon. Is that not what I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a field

```
field = getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
```

on whatever whatever type `this` is, presumably `com.whatever.project.Hexagon`. But then you try to retrieve the field on an object of type `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color`.

```
System.out.println(field.get(c));
```

This is wrong. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) states

> Returns the value of the field represented by this `Field`, on the
>   specified object.

`Color` does not have a `Color` field.

What you want is probably

```
field.get(this)
```